# Entity property value, which can be a number or a string, how can I handle this?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity

I have an entity which contians the property value. This value is sometimes a number (int) or sometimes a string.

For example:
I have the entity CarSpecification:

```
public class CarSpecification : BaseEntity
    {
        public virtual Car Car{ get; set; }

        public virtual Specification Specification { get; set; }

        public double Value { get; set; }
    }
```

This refers to the car and to the specification with the name "drive" and the Value "all-wheel drive".

It also refers to the same car and to the specification with the name "doorCount" and the Value 2.

It may be true that some values can occurred several times.

The entity for Specifications:

```
public class Specification : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Measure Measure { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ComponentSpecification> ComponentSpecifications { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean, that `CarSpecification.Value` can store number or string?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, there are 3 options:

1) store values in a string column with additional column `value_type`;
 2) store values in a separate columns (like `string_value`, `int_value`).   This could be done with or without `value_type` column;
 3) make a class hierarchy for values. Something like:

```
public abstract class Value { }
public class StringValue : Value {}
public class IntValue : Value {}
```

Obviously, for 2 and 3 the more types you need to store, the more columns/types you need to maintain. Option 3 I'd consider only if you need to store some exotic value types, which requires some additional data to be handled, because it most expensive - even in TPH case this is additional table + `JOIN` for queries.

I'd vote for 1, because it is simple. The only thing you need to care of, is a format settings when converting to of from string.

Comment: Thank you! I choose the first option.